# is a view's "tag" restored when the activity whose layout contains the view is recreated?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-view, android-lifecycle

The [docs](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html) concerning `Activity` recreation state:

> By default, the system uses the Bundle instance state to save
>   information about each View object in your activity layout (such as
>   the text value entered into an EditText object). So, if your activity
>   instance is destroyed and recreated, the state of the layout is
>   restored to its previous state with no code required by you.

The [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag%28java.lang.Object%29) for View.setTag(Object) state:

> Sets the tag associated with this view. A tag can be used to mark a
>   view in its hierarchy and does not have to be unique within the
>   hierarchy. Tags can also be used to store data within a view without
>   resorting to another data structure.

My question is:  if I set a tag on a View (that has a unique id) in my activity's layout and then the activity is destroyed by the system and subsequently re-created, will that view, when recreated, automatically be tagged with the Object I originally set?

Comment: Haven't tried but technically, it wouldn't make much sense. The `Object` could be anything and it would be suicide for the system to restore a reference to an Object which it doesn't have under control (it can't be included in the Bundle, it's not clear whether a shallow copy makes sense, etc),

Comment: The system expects to recreate the activity at some later date, so I could see it keeping around a reference to the original tag.  I'll test the behavior and report back.  Would have been nice if this had been documented.

Comment: Tell me about it. ;) BTW, the `visibility` attribute will _not_ be stored while many others are. -- It it were an `int` or something, I'd say okay, but the `Object` reference will be invalid by the time the activity gets re-created. But I'm curious what you'll find out.

Comment: Good to know about visibility.  I modify view visibility programmatically *a lot* based on user actions.  I was hoping that info would get saved as part of each view's instance state.  Bummer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> if I set a tag on a View (that has a unique id) in my activity's layout and then the activity is destroyed by the system and subsequently re-created, will that view, when recreated, automatically be tagged with the Object I originally set?

No, based on my reading of the source code.

> The system expects to recreate the activity at some later date, so I could see it keeping around a reference to the original tag.

That is not always possible, as the saved instance state `Bundle` needs to be transportable across process boundaries.