# Questions on android destroying and re-creating an activity

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Below documentation page mentions that android may destroy an activity instance in certain occasions and re-create it later with its previously saved state.

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

I want to know what would happen in below two scenarios if the activity is destroyed and re-created.

1) The activity has an anonymous `AsyncTask` running, which sets some values to UI elements on completion. If activity is destroyed while `AsyncTask` is still running, what would happen when `AsyncTask` gets finished? If some UI elements were accessed on `onPostExecute()`, will it result in an exception? If not, will the changes done in `onPostExecute()` be visible when the activity is re-created?

2) If some object is set as a tag in  `View` element using [View.setTag()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag%28java.lang.Object%29), after destroying and re-creating the activity, will the object set as the tag still be available in re-created view?

Comment: on the second point: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16172637/is-a-views-tag-restored-when-the-activity-whose-layout-contains-the-view-is-r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) It will throw an exception if you try to access UI elements from an old Activity object.  Internally, an entirely new Activity object is created, along with new View objects, meaning old references won't be valid.  Keep in mind you will leak memory with your AsyncTask if you hold a hard reference.

2) The same thing happens here.  A new View object is created, and all member variables of the old View are lost.

Only data saved in the `onSaveInstanceState()` method will carry over.  You can easily test this scenario by enabling "Don't Keep Activities" in your phone's developer options, or even with orientation changes.  You can also verify with the debugger whether a new object reference is created.

Answer (score 1):

To add to other people's comments, if you're going to be running an AsyncTask, one of the first things you should do in your onPostExecute method is check the activity status:

```
if (!isFinishing()) { ... }
```

Fragments have similar logic

```
if (isAdded() && !getActivity().isFinishing()) { ... }
```

Personally, i prefer to use RxJava with the RxLifecyle extensions, as it make it much cleaner to deal with, but that's a story for another day.

Answer (score 0):

when Async Task completes, the AsyncTask won't update the UI of the new Activity. Indeed it will try to updates  the former instance of the activity which in real sense doesnot exist. so this could lead to exception of some kind IllegalArgumentException or illegalStateException

why dont you  try by  just creating async task of  loops of 1000 iteration and press back to destroy the activity and see the result